# logback - no end of line delimiter

Tags: java, logging, logback

I'm using **logback 0.9.21** . Unfortunately it prints all messages to single line, there is **no end of line character**, even wrong one.

I've got the pattern set right AFAIK:

```
<pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %class (%thread) [%logger{36}] -- %msg%n</pattern>
```

What's the catch?

Comment: Which platform are you using? With which tool are you viewing the logs? What does a hexeditor say about the linebreak?

Comment: Hexeditor found no linbreak. The reason was there was no end of line at all as the line was truncated. It was quite easy to overlook it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Found it, round brackets have special meaning in the pattern layout, therefore they must be escaped.
So the pattern should look this way:

```
<pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %class \(%thread\) [%logger{36}] -- %msg%n</pattern>
```

Comment: I had a similar issue. My pattern was "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5level [%t][%logger}] - %m %ex%n". The problem was the extra } after %logger. Logback version 1.2.3 + java8

Answer (score 4):

In logback, parentheses within the pattern string serve as [grouping token](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#Parentheses)s.

They need to be escaped with a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

For any troubled soul like my self, Logback behave this way when it found a miss match token, not just parenthesis,

in my case was a miss placed `:-` token