# Bizarre "18 chars" LOGBack behaviour

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, logback

This is my first time using Logback - normally use log4j - been forced into it by a dependency.

I used the online converter for `log4j.properties` --> `logback.xml`.

When I run the application, all I get are the first 18 chars of any log line, without a newline at the end. The resulting output, both on the console and in the log file is:

```
16:32:00.537 (main16:32:00.537 (main16:32:00.537 (main16:32:00.537 
(main16:32:00.537 (main16:32:00.537 (main16:32:00.537 (main16:32:00.537 (main
```

What on earth could possibly be causing this?

The logback.xml is

```xml
<configuration>
  <appender name="xyzzy" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <File>xyzzy.log</File>
    <encoder>
      <charset>UTF-8</charset>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} (%t) %-5p [%c{36}] - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>xyzzy.log.%d</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
  </appender>
  <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <charset>UTF-8</charset>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} (%t) [%c{36}] %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <logger name="com.package" level="DEBUG"/>
  <logger name="org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies" level="ERROR"/>
  <root level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="xyzzy"/>
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know LOGBack but, [according to the documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html), 
I'm pretty sure that

```
(%t)
```

should be

```
[%t]
```

and it is exactly the point where your pattern breaks...

Try then with:

```
<pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5p [%c{36}] - %msg%n</pattern>

[...]

<pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] [%c{36}] %msg%n</pattern>
```

assuming all the rest is fine...

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly the reason, and very logically deduced too. Having tried this out, then a google search for "logback brackets" revealed this near duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944364/logback-no-end-of-line-delimiter

Comment: Nice, then you can do it by escaping the round brackets, good to know

Answer (score 3):

In logback, parenthesis in within the pattern string serve as [grouping tokens](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#Parentheses). They need to be escaped.